# The filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: batch-file

I am running this .bat file after the TFS build in VS 2010. But it is throwing an error says **"The filename directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"**

My batch file contains the following:

```
REM "*******START :Modify the following sections*******"
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64

set ProjectPath=C:\Builds\1\xxxx\xxx\Sources

Set PATH=%PATH%;%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0

REM  "------Move to the Project Folder------"
cd /c %ProjectPath%
cd  C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxxx\TestResults

REM  "------Find the latest Test Result file------"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d "C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxxx\TestResults\*.trx"') do (
   set latesttrxfile=%%a & goto :done
)
:done

echo %latesttrxfile%

REM  "------Move to test results folder------"
cd C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxxx\TestResults

REM  "------Convert trx to html------"
trx2html "C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxxx\TestResults\%latesttrxfile%"

REM  "------Find the latest Test Result html file------"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d "C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxx\TestResults\*.htm"') do (
   set latesthtml=%%a & goto :done
)
:done

echo %latesthtml%

REM  "------Send Email------"
sendEmail.exe -s xxx.xxx.xxx.com -f yyyy@xxx.com -t yyyy@xxx.com -u Test Report attached -a "C:\Builds\1\xxx\xxx\TestResults\%latesthtml%" -m TestReportAttached

Pause
```

Comment: Hi,                                                                               I am not able to figure our at what point it fails since i could see that error after the build results after the build has been completed. When I see the build results this error is there after the build execution has completed.                                                Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the issue was that my batch file was Unicode (default for a text file in VS 2010, it seems).

*File > Advanced Save Options* and change to *Western* fixed the problem.

Comment: Selecting ANSI encoding in notepad++ also worked for me.